# Can't correctly use external text file the way I used a literal list

Tags: ruby, encoding, io

I move a comparison of a list of words to a text file which I now try to bring in using `IO.gets` on each line. This has completely altered my results.

Basically I'm using a Trie to figure out if a prefix is inside a word - now my output is only showing the prefixes which means none of them are "matching" correctly and defaulting to returning all of the prefixes.

Is this an encoding issue or what's going on?

Here's the specific code I'm speaking of - so as opposed to:

```
sources = ['Bash', 'cplusplus', 'java',  'javascript', 'php', 'python', 'ruby']
prefixes = ['ab', 'ba', 'bu', 'Jav', 'ph', 'ru', 'ze']
```

I do this now:

```
def fileList(dir, array)
  file = File.new(dir, "r")
  while (line = file.gets)
    array << line
  end
end

sources = Array.new
prefixes = Array.new

fileList("../lists/sources.list", sources)
fileList("../lists/prefixes.list", prefixes)
```

With each element having its own line in the text file

https://github.com/jphenow/merge_prefix/tree/master/ruby

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: Please try to isolate your problem down to something you can place in-line with the question to make it as easy to answer as possible.

Comment: I tried to clean it up, but I'm not even entirely sure what the actual problem is - mostly I know that switching from a literal list to a text file that I get via `IO` is now outputting incorrectly. I'm trying to debug as best I can so I'll try to provide more information as I find it.

Comment: Show the part of the code that you use to read the file, show part of the file and show how you used to put the contents in your code (the working one). This way we can figure out what is going on.

Comment: Ok, sorry for trying to do it with putting much code in the actual, description - silly me! I've added all that's changed between my working literal arrays to pulling in per-line via text file.

I feel like its worth noting that I do get output (all prefixes) just not the _correct_ output - it doesn't seem to compare the strings as it did before

Comment: You might need to chomp the newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not real clear what you are trying to accomplish, but here's how to read the lines of files and append them to an array, which is a common-enough task:

The source files look like:

sources.list:

```
Bash
cplusplus
java
javascript
php
python
ruby
```

and

prefixes.list:

```
ab
ba
bu
Jav
ph
ru
ze
```

The code looks like:

```
require 'pp'

def fileList(dir, array)
  array += File.readlines(dir).map(&:chomp)
end

sources = Array.new
prefixes = Array.new

pp fileList("sources.list", sources)
pp fileList("prefixes.list", prefixes)

 => ["Bash", "cplusplus", "java", "javascript", "php", "python", "ruby"]
 => ["ab", "ba", "bu", "Jav", "ph", "ru", "ze"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def file_list(dir, array)
    Dir.chdir dir
    Dir.glob("*").each{|file| array << file}    
end
```

It's unusual for a method to change a variable's value but it will happen because of a quirk of array#<<. It's more common for the method to return the value:

```
def file_list(dir, array)
    Dir.chdir dir
    array + Dir.glob("*")
end

sources = fileList("./somedir", sources)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - forget to just use return sometimes!